# retrieve data AngularJS and spring MVC

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I want to make search by AngularJS and spring MVC but the following code didn't work There are no errors in eclipse console or web console

This is Spring MVC Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "app/rest/contacts/search",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<Contact> find(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name) {
    List<Contact> queryResults = contactRepository.search(name);
    return queryResults;
}
```

This is AngularJS Service

```
 pagingpocApp.factory('Contact', function ($http) {
 return {
        search: function(name) {
            var promise = $http.get('app/rest/contacts/search',{params: {name: name}}).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
            return promise;
        }
 }
  });
```

this is AngularJS Controller

```
pagingpocApp.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, $filter,resolvedContact, Contact) {
$scope.search= function() {
    Contact.search($scope.name).then(function(obj) {
        console.log(obj)
                  });
    }
   });
```

Html Page

```
<input ng-model="name">
<input type="submit" ng-click="search()">
```

Comment: Use your browser's debugging tool to watch the network traffic, turn up Web MVC logging to DEBUG and see if the requests are going through, and make sure that if that's not a `@RestController` you use `@ResponseBody`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct There are no errors ,Make sure you not use function name more than one, may you use search name in two function in angular controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Change this line to

```
var promise = $http.get('app/rest/contacts/search',{params: {name: name}}).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
```

to

```
var promise = $http.get('app/rest/contacts/search',{params: {name: name}});
```

Then in ContactController, doing obj.data should give you the data.